# How to handle "loop apps"?

Tags: android, optimization, android-activity

My app contains 3 activitys: A1, A2 and A3.

There is a "loop" between these activitys:
A1--starts--> A2 --starts--> A3 --starts--> A1 and so on.

Furthermore it's possible to go back from A3 to A2 and from A2 to A1 (only these 2 cases)

My Problem is, that my App becomes very sluggish after clicking through the activitys. I think its because the activitys aren't closed correctly. I can't finish the activitys A1 and A2 after starting the next one, because it's (how i said) possible to go back.

How can i handle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: single instance? I think not. A3 starts A1 via "startActivity(intent)"

Comment: A1-> A2 -> A3 -> A1 ( New Instance ) ...do want like this ..or want to launch the first A1 ?

Comment: reuse activities, do not create new one

Comment: The app get sluggish? Sound like a different problem, if Android don't have enough memory anymore, the activity will be terminated. 
I suggest you, to start the activities with the single top flag.

Comment: @GDG: it's better to reuse A1. would be better.. how to do it?

Comment: @Leandros: what is it good for to start activitys with that flag?

Comment: <activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are at Activity A3 and want to launch Activity A1 again then do..

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA1.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

It would clear the stack and would relaunch the Activity A1

Comment: Do i need the code of your comment above? <activity .. android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />

Comment: I wouldn't add clear top, because it would clear the backstack and confuse the user.